# postgresql - join tables with limit

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I want to show a user of his purchase summary from each store, up to first 3 purchases from each store.
For simplicity sake, the number of purchases is not configurable. So, it is not the first N, but the first 3

Let say I have these tables with these columns

```
Store
    id
    name

Product
    id
    name
    storeId
    price

Purchase
    id
    userId
    productId
    count
    purchaseTime
```

This is what I want to display

```
-----------------------------------------------
| store     | product         | count | price |
-----------------------------------------------
| disney    | stitch doll     | 1     | 30  |
|           | donald cap      | 3     | 15  |
|           | ticket          | 2     | 100 |
-----------------------------------------------
| universal | iron man figure | 1     | 100 |
|           | batman figure   | 1     | 90  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Preferably, if the user purchases donald caps on 2 separate purchases (assumed that price will never change), the number of purchases will be combined

for example: if the user purchases 2 donald caps and then purchase 1 cap, the result will be 3 donald caps - instead of 2 donald caps & 1 donald cap

I am using hibernate and postgresql

I don't even know where to start, in particular how to limit each store purchases to 3 for each store

Any hint, psudo solution or solutions will be appreciated

thanks

**Note:**
Unfortunately, there is a major oversight on my part.
I think I want to get each summary in 1 line

For example

```
id | Store     | Product1        | count1 | price1 | Product2      | count2 | price2 | Product3 | count3 | price3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Disney    | stitch doll     | 1      | 30     | donald cap    | 3      | 15     | ticket    | 2     | 100
5  | Universal | iron man figure | 1      | 100    | batman figure | 1      | 90     | null      | null  | null
```

The reason is: I need to paginate the result - displaying 10 purchase summaries per page
If each summary returns 1-3 rows, it is hard to figure out the result of the next page

Comment: "*the number of purchases will be combined*" so using `sum(count)` for all those purchases? Or just `count(*)`. What about the price column? Should that show the price for a single purchase or the sum of all products purchases e.g. is the price 15 for 3 caps calculated as 3 * 5 or is that the price for a single cap?

Comment: Sum(count). The price will be the individual price. Thanks

Comment: @Budi How your question related to the `hibernate` ?

Comment: So you want to aggregate the purchases for each product/store combination. Do you want to limit to 3 "purchase" _after_ that aggregation? Or before the aggregation? i.e. if done before, 3 purchases of the same product would show up as one row in the output.

Comment: Sql can be written as hql (hibernate query language). After finding the right sql, I may re-wtite it as hql (for portability reason)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Limit 3 after agregation

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lateral join to retrieve the first 3 purchases of each store:

```
select s.name, p.*
from store s
cross join lateral (
    select pr.name as product, pu.count, pr.price
    from purchase pu
    inner join product pr on pr.id = pu.productid
    where pr.storeid = s.id and pu.userid = ?
    order by pu.purchasetime
    limit 3
) p
```

Alternatively, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select pr.name as product, pu.count, pr.price,
        row_number() over(partition by s.id order by pu.purchasetime) rn
    from purchase pu
    inner join product pr on pr.id = pu.productid
    inner join store s on s.id = pr.storeid 
    where pu.userid = ?
) t
where rn <= 3
```

Comment: I got this ERROR: column "pr.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function on 2nd solution, and same error with "pr.name" on 1st solution. thanks

Comment: @Budi: this query cannot raise that error. You probably have incorporated it in another query that has a `group by` clause.

Comment: I got this error after I adapt names to reflect my actual database. In any case, there is an oversight on my part. I updated my requirement. If you have time, please give me a hint how to tackle that. thanks